# Error while creating new object in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, object, syntax-error

I am getting this error in rails whenever i am trying to create an object for the model. I am working on Windows 7

```
C:\Ruby\joker\chapter3>ruby script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.8)
>> mycb = ComicBook.new
SyntaxError: C:/Ruby/joker/chapter3/app/models/comic_book.rb:19: syntax error, u
nexpected $end, expecting kEND
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_suppo
rt/dependencies.rb:380:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_suppo
rt/dependencies.rb:380:in `load_file'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_suppo
rt/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_suppo
rt/dependencies.rb:379:in `load_file'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_suppo
rt/dependencies.rb:259:in `require_or_load'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_suppo
rt/dependencies.rb:425:in `load_missing_constant'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_suppo
rt/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_suppo
rt/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
        from (irb):1
>>
```

I have also attached the image so that you can look at the model itself

[image]

Also I am attaching you the created model ComicBook

```
 C:\Ruby\joker\chapter3>ruby script/generate model ComicBook
      exists  app/models/
      exists  test/unit/
      exists  test/fixtures/
      create  app/models/comic_book.rb
      create  test/unit/comic_book_test.rb
      create  test/fixtures/comic_books.yml
      create  db/migrate
      create  db/migrate/20100923101842_create_comic_books.rb
```

The environment I am working is

```
Ruby version    1.8.7 (i386-mingw32)
RubyGems version    1.3.7
Rack version    1.1
Rails version   2.3.8
Active Record version   2.3.8
Active Resource version 2.3.8
Action Mailer version   2.3.8
Active Support version  2.3.8
Application root    C:/Ruby/joker/chapter3
Environment development
Database adapter    mysql
Database schema version 20100923101842
```

Looking forward for your help

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods `self.up` and `self.down` must be in the migration(db/migrate/20100923101842_create_comic_books.rb)

Clean class of the CookBook model must look like this:

```
class CookBook < ActiveRedord::Base
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Last 'end'  missing  in your code (models/comic_book.rb)